# How to get the exact element edited within a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, contenteditable, keyup

I have a contenteditable div with a keyup event attached to it. There are many `p` tags created within that div as the user types.

```
$(".pad").keyup(function(e) {
    doSomething();
});
```

That's the `keyup` event.

How could I work out which element the user has edited/created within the contenteditable div?

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$(".pad p").keyup(function(e) {
    doSomething();
});
```

The goal is to have something like this:

```
$(".pad").keyup(function(e) {
    theEditedElement = ...;
    $(theEditedElement).css("color","red");
    $(theEditedElement).(...);
});
```

We start off with:

```
<div class="pad" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

This is then edited by the user to:

```
<div class="pad" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <p>Even <b>more</b> text</p>
</div>
```

If the user decides to edit `<p>Some more text</p>`, then that specific `<p>` element should be retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your event target to be a child of a `div` that is content editable instead of the `div` itself, you need to set those child nodes to be `contenteditable` as well. You can do that dynamically like this.

```js
const contentEl = document.querySelector('.pad');
const paras = contentEl.childNodes;

// here, set contenteditable attribute for all paragraphs inside of that div
for (let i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
  if (paras[i].nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    paras[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  }
}

contentEl.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  // event.target will be the element that you are asking for 
  const theEditedElement = event.target;
  console.log(theEditedElement);
  theEditedElement.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<div class="pad">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <p>Even <b>more</b> text</p>
</div>
```

Note that you might need to run the piece of code that sets `contenteditable` attribute to `div`'s childs again, when a new `p` element is created inside of that `div`.

Another option would be to create mutation observer and let it handle the changes to the enclosing `div` in case any new paragraphs are added (let it set `contenteditable` attribute of the newly added paragraph).

```js
const contentEl = document.querySelector('.pad');
const paras = contentEl.childNodes;

for (let i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
  if (paras[i].nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    paras[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  }
}

contentEl.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  // event.target will be the element that you are asking for 
  const theEditedElement = event.target;
  console.log(theEditedElement);
  theEditedElement.style.color = 'red';
});

// this code here is just to demonstrate the change to the enclosing div
const addNewParagraph = () => {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  contentEl.appendChild(p);
  p.textContent = 'new paragraph';
};

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', addNewParagraph);

// create mutation observer
const config = { childList: true };
const callback = function(mutationList) {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('new paragraph has been added');
      // get the added node and set its contenteditable attribute
      mutation.addedNodes[0].setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    }
  }
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(contentEl, config);
```

```html
<button>add new paragraph</button>

<div class="pad">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <p>Even <b>more</b> text</p>
</div>
```